# What does it mean to have a literal in an condition for memory?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

Given the following example:

```
//this gets allocated
var foo = 42;

//what happens to 0?
if (foo > 0)
{
}
```

Out of curiostiy, what happens to the `0` in terms of memory consumption/instructions?

I always thought it is some instruction which is fired to the processor and forget. Nothing that needs to be stored in RAM (As long it is a literal and not a reference).

After taking part of this [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146574/discussion-between-draco18s-and-servy) I am a litte bit confused.

Does the `0` allocated in memory in some way? Does it need to be garbage collected? Is there a type of literal that could change the situation?

What happens under the hood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//this gets allocated
var foo = 42;
```

"allocated" is not really the right word; that's a value-type local on the stack; it isn't an "allocation" as such. It is just `ldc.i4 42`, `stloc.0`.

```
//what happens to 0?
if (foo > 0)
{
}
```

Again, this isn't an allocation; there is nothing to collect; this is just `ldloc.0`, `ldc.i4.0`, `cgt`, `brfalse.s`. No allocations. Everything here is just values on the stack. GC refers to the managed heap, i.e. objects.

In terms of implementation : entering the method reserves a known amount of space on the stack (calculated by the compiler). Leaving the method *does nothing* - it leaves that memory untouched and just subtracts that same number back from the in use stack space.

> So `0` is stored on the stack the same way as `foo`?

Not quite the same way; `foo` is a local, `0` is a transient. Basically locals come first, then the transient stack space starts after the locals. The transient stack space is used (at least in theory - the JIT may enregister it) for in-progress operations, including loading literal values. The transient area is only informally defined (the JIT understands it, but it isn't formally declared) - and only lasts for the duration of individual operations. Locals are per method scope.

Comment: Thank you very much. So `0` is stored on the stack the same way as `foo`?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt not quite the same way; `foo` is a local, `0` is a transient. Basically locals come first, then the transient stack space starts after the locals. The transient stack space is used (at least in theory - the JIT may enregister it) for in-progress operations, including loading literal values. The transient area is only informally defined (the JIT understands it, but it isn't formally declared) - and only lasts for the duration of individual operations. Locals are per method scope.